# Task Manager shows too many exe processes for Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I only have one tab open and six `chrome.exe` running. I have not added any plug-ins and have no extensions. There are no videos trying to play or sound on web page so six `exe` processes seem like a lot especially when I opened Chrome and landed here before going anywhere else. I've read several post and this still seems to be overkill even given the explanations I've seen so far.

I am utilizing Chrome 59.0.3071.29 (Official Build) beta (64-bit) on a Windows 7 Professional SP1 machine.

Is this normal because performance has became an issue lately?

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We are always glad to help, but could probably use a bit more detail to work with.  For starters, which operating system and version are you running?

Comment: I am using Version 59.0.3071.29 (Official Build) beta (64-bit) on windows 7 and thank you for the reply.

Comment: To clarify, it's windows 7 professional service pack 1

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly normal. I only know that because I've seen it on every system running Chrome, though I've never looked into why.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is normal for chrome to have 5-6 process running process because even if for one open tab it has separate process other than browser program and some daemon processes. It is used because to save chrome from collapsing even if some web app or plugin crashed. You can see for yourself what process chrome is running on your system.

Use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> or right click on empty space of tab bar of chrome. it will open chrome internal task manager.

Comment: Beat me by a second. +1

Comment: Thank you for your reply's. I forgot to mention that the internal task manager only shows three processes running which is another reason I thought it so strange. I guess I will have to accept that this is normal but I'm a bit suspicious about everything internet these days.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer I have tried to explore why there are many instances for chrome running at the same time:

**I have made some strange discoveries:**

- The first .exe instance, I discovered its responsible for prefetch (probably comes up because prediction service is enabled)

  see screenshot:

[image]

I would like to believe these services are responsible for using these extra `chrome.exe` instances

- The other instance was crashpad (probably for checking usage statistics and crash reports)
- The other instance was an extension process responsible "disabling client side phishing detection", these were two of them
- The next one I investigated was responsible for " enabling auto offline download"
- The other chrome.exe instance is associated with "service request channel" (not sure whats this about)
- Last but not least is associated with "disabling gl extensions - gpu driver bug workarounds"

These investigations were done on Chrome 57.02987, Process Lasso

Hope this helps.